# MVVMCross w/ Bugsense causes weird issues with binding EditText on Android

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross, bugsense

I ran into a very weird situation when I installed the BugSense package on my MVVMCross app.  Every time I type a letter into the EditText the cursor moves to the first character.  This is highly annoying as I have to arrow over to the end of the field to type the next character!

What I did was on the override of the "OnCreate" of my SplashScreenView I set up this:

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        BugSenseHandler.Instance.InitAndStartSession(new ExceptionManager(), ApplicationContext, "xxxxxxxx");
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
    }
```

When my splash screen goes away it moves to my LoginViewModel.  My axml for my Login View looks like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/white_full_box">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/table_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/table_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dialog_margin"
        android:padding="@dimen/zero"
        android:background="@drawable/white_full_box">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/password"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="username"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/table_margin"
            android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
            android:singleLine="true"
            local:MvxBind="Text UserName">
            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="password"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/table_margin"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            local:MvxBind="Text Password" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/loginButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/password"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dialog_margin"
            android:text="Login"
            style="@style/ButtonStyle"
            local:MvxBind="Click LoginCommand" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And I just have normal properties that bind to the Username, Password and Login button in the view model.  I did a couple things to verify this behavior:

1.)  I left the bugsense initialization code and removed the Text bind from the username.  In this scenario the username would behave properly but the password field would always move the character to the first character after each text entry.

2.)  I reimplemented the text bind to the username field and then commented out the BugSense initialization code and everything appeared to work correctly again.

What is happening here?  Where should I be doing the BugSense initialization in an MVVMCross app?

Comment: I get the same behavior if I move the BugSense code to the OnCreate override of my LoginView.... I'm now moving it to the OnCreate override of my MainView which appears to solve the issue unless something else pops up later in testing.

Comment: This did not fix the issue.  MOving the StartAndInit to my MainView now causes activities that are created after the MainView to have the same issue.  Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to switch to Raygun.io because that does not appear to have the same issue.

Bugsense does appear to be looking into the issue which you can follow along [HERE](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/694)